# Get authentication token with MFA from Powershell

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My company implemented Privileged Identity Management and I'm trying to make my life a bit easier by requesting a role straight from a Powershell script. I'm logging in with <s>Connect-AzureAD</s> Connect-MGGraph but it doesn't ask for my MFA which is a requirement to request a role assignement (and that's good thing, too). Yes, I want this to run interactively!

I've read through this guys post but it requires setting up an application registration which is completely stupid: http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2020/02/connect-to-azure-ad-powershell-with-mfa.html

There must be a way to request a login with MFA through Powershell/Microsoft Graph without having to create an app registration. Anybody have any idea?

**edit**: removed my script because I learned that the AzureAD Powershell Module's days are numbered. Trying the same thing through Microsoft Graph but I still need to force MFA on the session:

> To run this request, the calling user must have multi-factor authentication (MFA) enforced, and running the query in a session in which they were challenged for MFA - ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-post-roleassignmentschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell#example-2-user-activating-their-eligible-role))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way 'Anuj Chandhary' (see link in post) does it, is not stupid. He's connecting to a well-known client ID representing the Graph API. Only too bad he doesn't explain that in his article. It didn't work for me because the version of my MSAL.PS Powershell module was too old. Updated that and it works now, now I only need to port the script to the Graph API

tldr: update MSAL.PS module

Answer (score 0):

The AzureAD PowerShell module is going to be depreciated.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/azure-ad-change-management-simplified/ba-p/2967456

<strike>It looks like you can do what you want through Microsoft Graph. I found this on a quick Google search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-assign-graph</strike>

Graph Explorer is a fantastic tool for testing things out:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Ditto to what 'shawnzzzy', said, but as for your comment, regarding the link you point to, my question is, does it work? You may not like the approach, but, again does it work?  Did you try it? What were your results? Just curious.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the AzureAD module is ending. The link you shared wasn't what I needed but it got me searching and I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-post-roleassignmentschedulerequests?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell#example-2-user-activating-their-eligible-role
That doesn't change the fact that I still need to enforce MFA on this session. As stated in the above article: 'To run this request, the calling user must have multi-factor authentication (MFA) enforced, and running the query in a session in which they were challenged for MFA'

Comment: @postanote I'm fairly certain it would work with an app registration but I'm not curious enough to test it. Never going to use it like that anyway. It's meant to distribute among colleagues and also use it for customer tenants.

Comment: Hofa, your right that was a bad link, yours is much better. I'm going to test it.

Comment: Hofa, does Connect-MgGraph not present you with an MFA requirement either? If not, is your account configured to require MFA?

Comment: Conditional Access Rules dictate that MFA is not necessary when working from the office. So it's not always enforced. The link in my original post did work, check out my other reply (will be able to mark it as the solution as from tomorrow)